# Creating a DOM element with jQuery - does not implement "node"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, codemirror

I'm currently implementing [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net) and I'm trying to use the [`addLineWidget` function](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addLineWidget).

It's second parameter takes a `DOM Node`, so I thought to construct it with jQuery like this:

```
var widget = $('<span class="ct-description-widget">' + descr + '</span>').get();
```

However, when I pass it to the function, it throws an exception:

> TypeError: Value does not implement interface Node.

How can I make it a true `Node`? Note that I cannot append it anywhere into the DOM!

Comment: @billyonecan oh, that did it. I should have seen the square brackets in firebug :)

Comment: @billyonecan: Did you meant `.get(0)`??

Comment: @PalashMondal .get()[0] give same result as .get(0) of course but the usual syntax is to pass index as param

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont know codemirror and not sure what you call a true node. But to return the first DOM element matched, you need to use get(0):

```
var widget = $('<span class="ct-description-widget">' + descr + '</span>').get(0);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
var widget = $('<span class="ct-description-widget">' + descr + '</span>')[0];
```

Comment: Not totally really, `.get` provides negative indexes feature, but that's the right answer. Great!

Comment: @LightStyle nice point! Ya, get() let us to use negative index to start from the end.